# How to check remove numbers from a string?

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm using an SSIS package to bring data through data from one table to another. However, I have a predicament where a field in the table(GroupName) brings through data with numbers at the end. This comes in two forms, either the string will be a name and then a set of numbers less than 4 characters in length. (E.g - Group Name 22)

Or it will come as a name and four numeric characters. (E.g Group Name 2012). Now I'd like to do a check on the data in SQL to see if the length of numeric characters at the end of the string is less than 4. If so, remove the numbers.

Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

You can use patindex

```
SELECT
     SUBSTRING('Group Name 2012'
    ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%'
    ,'Group Name 2012')
    ,LEN('Group Name 2012')) as NumberOnly
    ,LEN( SUBSTRING('Group Name 2012'
    ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%'
    ,'Group Name 2012')
    ,LEN('Group Name 2012'))) as Numberlength
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively add a Derived column transformation with

```
NumericCheck= RIGHT(stringvariable,4)
```

and then in a separate Derived column transformation

```
(DT_I4)Numeric_check == (DT_I4)Numeric_check ? 1 : 0
```

Note: You will need to Configure the Error output to "Ignore Failure" for this check. Then have a conditional split which sends the zero values to be updated via an OLE DB Command